# How to reproduce IoSession in mina in Netty

Tags: java, tcp, netty, apache-mina

There is a project that wants to transition from mina to netty, but involves IoSession as a local session. So how to implement a similar session in Netty for use。

```
 private IoSession _session;
 if (immediately) {
      _session.closeNow();
 }else{
    _session.closeOnFlush();
 }
```

How to better implement this function

Comment: Can you add the mina code stub that you've tried, even if it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it would be something like:

```
 private ChannnelHandlerContext ctx;
 if (immediately) {
   ctx.close();
 } else {
   ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
 }
```